# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'trailer_youtube_url'

Tags: python, html

I keep getting this error AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'trailer_youtube_url' is not defined, I do not understand why. I am asking my mentor about this and she is at a loss, so I thought maybe someone here could help. I have added the code and error on this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jay\Documents\python code\Movie_project\entertainment_center.py", line 34, in <module>
    fresh_tomatoes.open_movies_page(movies)
  File "C:\Users\Jay\Documents\python code\Movie_project\fresh_tomatoes.py", line 159, in open_movies_page
    movie_tiles=create_movie_tiles_content(movies))
  File "C:\Users\Jay\Documents\python code\Movie_project\fresh_tomatoes.py", line 138, in create_movie_tiles_content
    r'(?<=v=)[^&#]+', movie.trailer_youtube_url)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'trailer_youtube_url'
```

This is the class

```
import webbrowser

class Movie():
    valid_ratings = ["G", "R", "PG-13", "R"]

    def __init__(self, movie_title, movie_storyline, poster_image,
               trailer_youtube):
        self.title = movie_title
        self.storyline = movie_storyline
        self.poster_image_url = poster_image
        self.trailer_youtube_url = trailer_youtube

    def show_trailer(self):
         webbrowser.open(self.trailer_youtube_url)
```

This is the where most of the code is

```
import fresh_tomatoes
import media


toy_story = media.Movie("Toy Story",
                        "A story of a boy and his toys come to life",
                        "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/13/Toy_Story.jpg",
                        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwyZH85NQC4")

The_devils_double = media.Movie("The_devils_double",
                                "The story of the son of sadam hussain's body double",
                                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/4c/The_Devil%27s_Double.jpg",
                                "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-MsGEWFiYg",)

Movie_300 = media.Movie("300",
                  "300 spartans vs an amry of persians",
                  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5c/300poster.jpg",
                  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDiUG52ZyHQ")

Ratatouille = media.Movie("Ratatouille",
                          "A rat is a chef in paris",
                          "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/50/RatatouillePoster.jpg",
                          "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3sBBRxDAqk")
Star_Wars_Episode_III = media.Movie("Star_Wars_Episode_III",
                                    "Akin Skywalker goes dark",
                                    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/93/Star_Wars_Episode_III_Revenge_of_the_Sith_poster.jpg",
                                    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UnjrG_N8hU")

Office_Space = media.Movie("Office_Space ",
                           "A movie about how work sucks",
                           "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8e/Office_space_poster.jpg",
                           "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kwQziVIzDeg")
movies = [toy_story, The_devils_double, 300, Ratatouille, Star_Wars_Episode_III , Office_Space  ]
fresh_tomatoes.open_movies_page(movies)
print(media.Movie.valid_ratings)
```

Comment: Why is movies commented out above?

Comment: You have `300` in the definition of `movies` instead of `Movie_300`—might be time to find another mentor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have added a `#` before the movies variable @line 47.
Just remove it.

---

There is a `300` on the 'movies' value, which is an integer. The variable you declared is called `Movie_300` instead.

the movies variable should look like this:

```
movies = [toy_story, The_devils_double, Movie_300, Ratatouille, Star_Wars_Episode_III , Office_Space]
```

Also, consider following the [Pep 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for the code styling.

Comment: Did you mean the # in #movies = [toy_story, The_devils_double, 300, Ratatouille, Star_Wars_Episode_III , Office_Space  ] or the in the html code, because I get this error AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'trailer_youtube_url' when I remove the # in the #movies = [toy_story, The_devils_double, 300, Ratatouille, Star_Wars_Episode_III , Office_Space  ]

Comment: Please include the full error traceback, also split the original code into files so there is a better readability.

Comment: I have added the error I get once I remove the # and also I split the code

Comment: Change `300` to `Movie_300`, that should fix the error (on the movies variable)